# unable to read data using dask

Tags: python, dask

I want to get sql data using dask.read_sql.

My code is

```
from dask.dataframe import read_sql_query, read_sql, read_sql_table

username='uid'
password='pid'
database='myDB'
host='sql_server'
port='1433'
driver='ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'

conn_str = f"mssql+pyodbc://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?driver={driver}"

ddf = read_sql_query(sql="select * from data", con=conn_str, index_col='id')
```

However, I got an error

```
File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\io\sql.py", line 118, in read_sql_query
    q = sql.limit(head_rows)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'limit'
```

How to solve this problem?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`read_sql_query()`](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.dataframe.read_sql_query.html) says that the `sql` parameter must be an SQLAlchemy [`Selectable`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/selectable.html#selectable-foundational-constructors), and can not be a string.

The SQLAlchemy documentation suggests something like this:

```
from dask.dataframe import read_sql_query
from sqlalchemy import table, column

data = table("data",
        column("id"),
        ..., # all the other columns in your table
)

conn_str = ... # constructed as before
ddf = read_sql_query(sql=data.select(), con=conn_str, index_col='id')
```

#### Quick Test for SQLAlchemy

You might want to test SQLAlchemy is working fine, so you can separate if the problem is with SQLAlchemy, dask, or something else. This code snippet should help you see if you're using SQLAlchemy correctly.

```
import sqlalchemy

data = table("data",
        column("id"),
        column("foo"),  # or whatever
)

conn_str = ...

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(conn_str)
# you don't have to use limit, but just in case your table is 
# not a demo table and actually has lots of rows
cursor = engine.execute(data.select().limit(1))
row = cursor.fetchone()
print(row)  # should print something like (1, 'abc')
```

Comment: It returns an error : AttributeError: 'Select' object has no attribute 'subquery'

Comment: The above works fine for me when I target a PostgreSQL database (driver changed accordingly). Are you using a different query that the one you put in your question? I don't know why it would be asking about a subquery otherwise. You should check that your connection through sqlalchemy works. I'll add a quick bit of code so you can check. If the problem is with sqlalchemy then that's becoming a different question.